# What is wrong with my pattern matching and replacement function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe with temperatures in the format XX,X instead of XX.X.

I can use the following code to successfully change them...

`df$tempMedian <- sub(",",".",df$tempMedian)
 df$tempMedian <- as.numeric(df$tempMedian)`

I've tried writing the following function to do the same thing:

`comma_to_point <- function(data, colname){
  data$colname <- sub(",", ".", data$colname)
  data$colname <- as.numeric(data$colname)
}`

When I call the function:

`comma_to_point(df, tempMedian)`

I get the following error:

"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, colname, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 365"

My dataframe is 365 obs long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
comma_to_point <- function(data, colname){
  data[[colname]] <- sub(",", ".", data[[colname]])
  data[[colname]] <- as.numeric(data[[colname]])
  return (data)
}
df = comma_to_point(df, "tempMedian")
```

When using a variable `var='my_column'` to reference a column in a `data.frame`, you can't do `df$var`, since R will think `var` is the name of the column. Instead you can get the column with `df[[var]]`.

Comment: That doesn't work. Throws this error: 
Error in comma_to_point(df, "tempMedian") : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: The edit *should* work, let me know if you still have an issue.